# What is the simplest way to change the appearance of the tristate state of a Python Tkinter checkbutton?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that uses a tristate tkinter checkbutton. The code works and the icons for on and off are fine, but I find the icon for tristate not visually distinctive enough. I'd rather not have to create images for all three states. What is the simplest way to change the appearance of just the tristate icon. (This is on Windows. It may be different on Apple).

Here is example code and an image of the result.

```
    root = Tk.Tk()
    var1 = Tk.StringVar(value="on")
    cb1 = Tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var1, text="on")
    cb1.pack(anchor="w")
    var2 = Tk.StringVar(value="off")
    cb2 = Tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var2, text="off")
    cb2.pack(anchor="w")
    var3 = Tk.StringVar(value="tristate")
    cb3 = Tk.Checkbutton(root, onvalue="on", offvalue="off", tristatevalue="tristate", variable=var3, text="tristate")
    cb3.pack(anchor="w")
    root.mainloop()
```

[image]